# Improve this design for DI and code reusability

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection, software-design, ooad

I want to inject implementations of IClasses into some other client class. The design currently is such that some functions have common code which I don't want to repeat across the implementations of IClasses. For this I have introduced an abstract class which stores the common functionality which implementations of IClasses will inherit from. I have the following class structures.

```
public interface IClasses
{
    string CommonFunc1();
    string CommonFunc2();

    string SpecialFunc1();
    string SpecialFunc2();

}

public abstract class BaseClass : IClasses
{
    public string CommonFunc1()
    {
        return "";
    }

    public string CommonFunc2()
    {
        return "";
    }

    public abstract string SpecialFunc1();
    public abstract string SpecialFunc2();
}

public class Imple1 :BaseClass, IClasses
{

    public override string SpecialFunc1()
    {
        return "11";
    }

    public override string SpecialFunc2()
    { return "12"; }
}

public class Imple2 :BaseClass, IClasses
{

    public override string SpecialFunc1()
    {
        return "21";
    }

    public override string SpecialFunc2()
    { return "22"; }
}
```

I want to know if this design can be improved? Visual studio keeps complaining that the Interface is redundant because everything is already there in the abstract class. I want to use an Interface only for DI in the consuming classes. How do I remove the redundancy if any?

Comment: Off-hand, I can't see anything to improve.  This is a pretty common pattern.  Though, I try to avoid going more than 1 to 2 levels deep in inheritance.  Any deeper than that, and it's probably better to move some functionality into separate interfaces/classes.  Also, in .NET, the common convention is upper camel-case all functions.

Comment: thanks Ken. Visual studio keeps complaining that the Interface is redundant because everything is already there in the abstract class, so I thought there is scope for improvement.

Comment: Guessing you're using Resharper or something.  My base VS install doesn't complain. As it, it is kind of redundant, but would probably change as your solution matures.  If you add virtual to both common functions in the base class, does it complain?  That's one thing I see missing.  Generally, you'll want to allow the subclasses to override those.

Comment: it only complains about `IClasses` in the `Imple1` class as it doesn't need the interface declaration as it inherits it from the abstract base class. This is correct and you can remove it. `Imple1` will still implement `IClasses`

Comment: @SamHolder: how can I pass Imple1 into a constructor using the interface IClasses as a parameter if I remove the ",IClasses" from the class definition of Imple1 here? I want to use interfaces only for DI not abstract classes.

Comment: @ken: I did not use virtual methods because I kind of don't like empty methods in my classes. I will try that out and let you know soon.

Comment: @user20358 even if you remove the `IClasses` declaration from the clas *it will still implement the `IClasses` interface as it inherits it from the base class* and so you will still be able to pass it to a method which takes an `IClasses` argument. Try it.

Comment: you're right @SamHolder :)

Comment: The big question I have is: Do all consumers of `IClasses` need ALL its methods? If not, you are violating the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and this is something you can improve.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement point @Steven

Answer (score 0):

Imple1 should not derive from IClasses interface, as it already derives from the BaseClass abstract class which is already deriving from the IClasses interface, that means that every class which derives from BaseClass now also derives from IClasses,

so youre code should look like that -

```
public class Imple1 :BaseClass
{

    public override string SpecialFunc1()
    {
        return "11";
    }

    public override string SpecialFunc2()
    { return "12"; }
}
```

that's is, it should not disrupt DI.